# How to use cPanel Email using only data connectivity?

Tags: email, cpanel, intranet, dedicated-server

Probably my title is misleading, but please hear me out. My client is using a cPanel dedicated server for Email and websites hosted by me.

They have 32 small regional office situated in different cities around the country. Their head office is in the capital city and it has the internet connectivity. The regional offices are connected to head office through IPSEC VPN (data connectivity) and they don't have any internet connectivity. They only use some insurance software through the data connectivity.

Now my question is, how can they use cPanel Email using only this data connectivity? Is it even possible? I am open to any kind of suggestion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this 'data connectivity'? I always assume data == internet.

Comment: Hello, by data connectivity means, intranet connectivity.